# Information Management Policy Settings

Tags: information-management

I need to edit a content type for a document library more specifically the Information Management Policy. When I go to edit it I get this (see screenshot)[image: Parent Policy]

So I'm guessing that this policy is controlled higher up?  Site level?  But I can't find it, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You could start with clicking the link in your message above, it will take you to the parent content type (probably the content type on the web and not the one on the document library)

Comment: Hi.  I've been to the link.  This takes me to a site content type which I can edit.  What I want to do is to add a label {Version} so that I can insert the version number of a document into a document as a quick part.  If I add the label I get this error. "There were errors on the page:
•The label reference, Version, could not be found."